# myFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function and have an error message "this.testFunc is not a function"

I think the problem is that the function is initialised in ComponentDidMount and then testFunc is not defined yet, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
var _receivedNb = 0

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

    this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );
  }


  handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic(data) {
      _receivedNb = this.testFunc();
  }

  testFunc() {
    var r = 2;
    return r;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `this` reference inside `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic` is not what you are thinking. You can learn about this in detail from [You Dont Know Js](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)

Coming to the solution there are multiple approaches to resolve this, you need to fix the `this` reference inside `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic`

One easy approach is using **ARROW FUNCTION =>**. Arrow functions preserve `this`  from the location where the function is defined.

```
var _receivedNb = 0

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

componentDidMount() {

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

    this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );
}


handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = (data) => {
    _receivedNb = this.testFunc();
}

testFunc = () => {
  var r = 2;
  return r;
}
```

Second approach is using **.call, .bind or .apply**. You can read about them later, In short bind takes `this` in params and return a hard-binded function with this always referring to what was provided inside `.bind`. You can simply use `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic.bind(this)` and call it. The best way to do this is inside `constructor`.

```
var _receivedNb = 0

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()  
        this.newHandleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic.bind(this)

    }

componentDidMount() {

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

    this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );
}


handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = (data) => {
    _receivedNb = this.testFunc();
}

testFunc = () => {
  var r = 2;
  return r;
}
```

and use `newHandleUpdateValueForCharacteristic` every where else.

**Call and apply** are similar to bind with only difference that it immediately calls the function with this reference and other required parameters passed inside call and apply.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your event handler

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Please give more details as to *why* he needs to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind that function in constructor. I hope following code will help,

```
var _receivedNb = 0

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.testFunc = this.testFunc.bind(this);
  }

  testFunc() {
    var r = 2;
    return r;
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false});

    this.handlerUpdate = bleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic );
  }


  handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic(data) {
      _receivedNb = this.testFunc();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the function `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic` as an arrow function in order to let it inherit the outer scope (that is the class scope) and you should be fine.

```
handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = data => {
  _receivedNb = this.testFunc();
}
```