# issue with set timeinterval in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to call a function in set time inter val for every 5 seconds but i throws errors in 
      TypeError: this.intialState is not a function

```
componentDidMount() { 
        this.intialState(); 
        setInterval(this.changeSelection,5000); 
    }
    changeSelection(){ 
        this.intialState(); 
    }

  TypeError: this.intialState is not a function
```

Comment: where is the `intialState` method declared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [myFunction is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235113/myfunction-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` loses its context inside functions. You can bind `changeSelection` in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.changeSelection = this.changeSelection.bind(this);
  setInterval(this.changeSelection, 500);
}
```

or make it a fat arrow function since these functions don't have their own `this` context and will take the parent's

```
changeSelection = () => {
  // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated 5-second countdown using `class Clock extends Component`

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Clock extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {currentCount: 10}
      }

      timer() {
        this.setState({
          currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1
        })
        if(this.state.currentCount < 1) { 
          clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timer.bind(this), 1000);
      }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      }

      render() {
        return(
          <div>{this.state.currentCount}</div>
        );
      }
    }

   export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `arrow` function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`

```js
componentDidMount() { 
  this.intialState(); 
  setInterval(this.changeSelection,5000); 
}
changeSelection = () => { 
  this.intialState(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function 'changeSelection' does not have access to 'this'.

There are two easy ways to solve this issue:

1. In your 'constructor', add this line to bind 'this' with changeSelection

`this.changeSelection = this.changeSelection.bind()`

2. An arrow function

`changeSelection = () => {};`

[Click here to see more ways to do binding](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

You can read more about why we need binding [why and how to bind](https://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/)